# SQL Error 1045 despite of correct credentials

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using the correct credentials in my Android Studio Project, but I always get a SQLException with unknown error 1045. I have no idea what I can do now. This is the line where the exception is thrown:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://png.services/dummy?user=dummy&password=test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
```

You can check the credentials from above here: 
https://png.services/phpmyadmin/

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this question has nothing in common with the question you marked as duplicate.

Comment: It is about an error 1045! Nothing in common? If your case is something else then edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The other question was about anonymous access at localhost, I made clear that I have used credentials (like mentioned in title)

Comment: I asked the question again, because @Seelenvirtuose mistakenly marked this as duplicate. The question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043470/sql-connection-error-with-correct-credentials-all-permissions-and-access-everyw/53052598#53052598