# SQL connection error with correct credentials, all permissions and access everywhere

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**This question hasn't been answered at stackoverflow, previously, so pls don't mark them as duplicate. I have tried all solutions before.**

I'm using the correct credentials in my Android Studio Project, but I always get a SQLException with unknown error 1045. I have no idea what I can do now. This is the line where the exception is thrown:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://png.services/dummy?user=dummy&password=test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
```

You can check the credentials from above here (they are real: `user: dummy` `password: test`): 
https://png.services/phpmyadmin/

What I have done so far:

- I checked, that the user can access the database from everywhere (not only localhost)
- The user has all permissions to the table
- In python the connection works with the same password

I guess, something is wrong with the connection string. The server's timezone is CEST.

Helpless stack trace:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Unknown error 1045
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at services.png.lena.database.MySQL.<clinit>(MySQL.java:32)
        at services.png.lena.MySQL_test.test_initMySQL(MySQL_test.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at 
 com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

    java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expected :services.png.lena.logic.DBResult@4c069e19
    Actual   :services.png.lena.logic.DBResult@10bdf9a6
```

Comment: Is the `getConnection` method by you? If so, please post the code. thanks

Comment: But does it work in Python with the same exact connection string?

Comment: @jr593 getConnection is from java.sql.DriverManager

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, not the exact connection string because it's not supported there I think. I only entered a username and password there, but this isn't working in Java because of a timezone problem.

Comment: Hi, I am new to this as well but have you specified the server hostname and port number?

Shouldn't it be `jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/....`

Comment: @JWiryo Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @JWiryo Port is optional and defaults to the MySQL default port of 3306 if it isn't specified in the connection string..

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Done

Comment: Which version of MySQL and which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using?

Comment: Try changing `... password=test?useUnicode=true ...` to `... password=test&useUnicode=true ...`

Comment: Don't you have to add username and password into the connection request?

Comment: This line worked for me:
String url = "jdbc:mysql://png.services/dummy?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

the 3 first tables in your db are:
CHARACTER_SETS
COLLATIONS
COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I used the wrong char. I had to change ... `password=test?useUnicode=true` ... to ... `password=test&useUnicode=true` ...

Thanks to Gord Thompson